# Why does the view not scrolls down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, steroids

everybody!
I'm writing a mobile app for ios using the framework steroids and css/html/js. Unfortunately, I can't understand, why can't I scroll down the view. Please, help.

the html-code of the screen

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Teachers</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/ionic/css/ionic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/stylesheets/application.css" />

  <script src="/javascripts/onerror.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/console.log.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova.js is served from localhost to ensure the correct version -->
  <script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/steroids-js/steroids.js"></script>

  <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="grid">

     <img src="teachers/bobr.jpg">
     <h3>Боброва Даша</h3>
     <p>Математический анализ</p>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <img src="teachers/korolev.jpg">
        <h3>Королев Даня</h3>
        <p>Программирование 1</p>
    </div>
        <div class="grid">
        <img src="teachers/mayb.jpg">
    <h3 >Майборода Кирилл</h3>
     <p>Программирование 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid">
    <img src="teachers/mosh.jpg">
    <h3 >Монгольский фанк</h3>
    <p>Ла-ла</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and part of css

```
body {
    /* Background color set as workaround for Legacy Android issue:
    https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/381 */
    background-color:#fff;

}



.grid{
width: 100%;
height: 33%;
clear: both;
display: inline-block;
}


.grid img{

    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    width: 33%;
    height:96%;
    float: left;


}
.grid h3{
    font-size: 300%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4%;


}
.grid p{

    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have declared , because this style for the body is declared in the default css file and neccessary for the simulation of the app on android/iphome.